# MVC Controller using related data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hope someone can help me with this.

I have a controller in my ASP.NET MVC project that is used for editing a so called survey form. The survey form has a 1-to-1 relation with objects of type Form. When saving the survey form I also want to set the name of the form. However the form property is null. The FormID property has the correct value (using database first, EF5). Here is the problem.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SurveyForm surveyform)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(surveyform).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // This cannot be done because surveyform.Form is null
            surveyform.Form.Name = "Wish this would work!";


            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I 'attach' surveyform to the model so that is loads related data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you passing `SurveyForm` as a parameter to Edit method? Are you POSTing it?

Comment: Yes it's a post. It is like the scaffolding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say the entity being POSTed back isn't being tracked, so Entity Framework doesn't realise it's from the database. The line `db.Entry(surveyForm)` gets the entry matching the POSTed form, but you're not retaining it. Try this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SurveyForm surveyform)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var formEntry = db.Entry(surveyform);

        formEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        formEntry.Form.Name = "This might work...";

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Hopefully, the `.Entry()` will get you the database's version. Unfortunately, you'll probably have to copy the property values accross, although you might find you can use `.Attach()` and then copy over the navigation properties from the database's version.

Having said that, it's generally a good idea to not use your database models in the view if you can help it; separation of concerns and all that. If there's more than a couple of properties on that model that are needed for the database but not the view (or vice versa) then you might want to use a local view model for it and just copy the properties to a freshly-retrieved database entity.

Comment: Separation of concerns is ofcourse always a winning lotery number, but actually I thought that this (automatically creating an object and copying the properties from the form post) was one of the gems of Microsoft's implementation of MVC. I took the scaffolding as good practice and so using the objects from the model felt the right way and pretty natural.

Comment: I have to admit, I do like that feature - it's one of the reasons I like Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC as a combo. If done right, you can keep your EF classes pretty clean, in which case separate viewmodels aren't really required. There's also the `Bind` attributes you can use to prevent over-POSTing and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
db.Entry(surveyform).Reference(x => x.Form).Load();
surveyform.Form = db.Entry(surveyform).Reference(x => x.Form).CurrentValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, make sure you have a navigation propery like this:

```
public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
```

And then in your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<SurveyForm>().HasOptional(p => p.Form);
 }
```

HasOption can be replaced with HasRequired.

I have never had the exact issue you are having, so I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I combined multiple suggestions above and ended up with the following.

I added the following to my view:

```
    @Html.TextBox("formName", Model.Form.Name)
```

and then changed the code in my controller to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string formName, SurveyForm surveyForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var surveyFormEntry = db.Entry<SurveyForm>(surveyForm);
            db.SurveyForms.Attach(surveyForm);
            surveyFormEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

            surveyFormEntry.Reference(x => x.Form).Load();
            surveyForm.Form = db.Entry(surveyForm).Reference(x => x.Form).CurrentValue;
            surveyForm.Form.Name = formName;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { surveyId = surveyForm.SurveyID });
        }
```

It was a lot of trial and error. A way of programming I so disapprove on and dislike but I'm happy it finally works.

Thanks all!